# Error of JAX-RS

Tags: jax-rs

First,please let me aplogize my english is not good. because I'm Japanese.
I ask,error of JAX-RS project.
I import a sample of the following sites:
http://www.opentone.co.jp/news/release/article04/article0403.html
but i can't be executed that project.

I think "Starting the context failed due to previous errors: Critical"　is prime importance.
How they could be solved What if?

And if possible the above sites Please try to import to eclipse the project actually.
You can download the "添付のファイル" from the attached.Near the bottom of the page it.

It is over, thank you.

this is web.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

      <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
      </listener>

      <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
      </context-param>

      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>

      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
        </web-app>
```

this is stack trace

```
9 23, 2014 5:18:07 午後 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
重大: クラス org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener のリスナインスタンスにコンテキスト初期化イベントを送信中の例外です
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [jp.sample.jaxrs.service.HelloResource] for bean with name 'helloResource' defined in file [C:\Users\omiz12032\workspace3\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\jax-rs\WEB-INF\classes\jp\sample\jaxrs\service\HelloResource.class]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: jp/sample/jaxrs/service/HelloResource : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class jp.sample.jaxrs.service.HelloResource)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1330)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:896)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:566)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4709)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:822)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: jp/sample/jaxrs/service/HelloResource : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class jp.sample.jaxrs.service.HelloResource)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2858)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1159)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1647)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:257)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1282)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1253)
    ... 24 more

9 23, 2014 5:18:07 午後 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
重大: Error listenerStart
9 23, 2014 5:18:07 午後 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
重大: 以前のエラーのためにコンテキストの起動が失敗しました [/jax-rs]
9 23, 2014 5:18:07 午後 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
情報: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
9 23, 2014 5:18:07 午後 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
情報: Coyote HTTP/1.1を http-8080 で起動します
9 23, 2014 5:18:07 午後 org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
情報: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
9 23, 2014 5:18:07 午後 org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
情報: Jk running ID=0 time=0/21  config=null
9 23, 2014 5:18:07 午後 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
情報: Server startup in 4681 ms
```

anf this is applicationContext.xml.Those for registering a web service

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd">

  <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />

  <context:component-scan base-package="jp.sample.jaxrs" />

  <jaxrs:server id="jaxrsservice" address="/">
      <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
          <ref bean="helloResource" />
      </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
  </jaxrs:server>

  <jaxrs:server id="itemorderresource" address="/">
      <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
          <ref bean="itemOrderResource" />
      </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
  </jaxrs:server>

  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/jaxrs" />
    <property name="username" value="jaxrs" />
    <property name="password" value="jaxrs" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:mybatis-config.xml" />
    <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath:mybatis/**/*.xml" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Please ad stack trace with your exceptions to the post and web.xml file.

Comment: Thank you for reply.I added to the text a stacktrace and web.xml

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: jp/sample/jaxrs/service/HelloResource : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class jp.sample.jaxrs.service.HelloResource)

Basically it means that you compiled your classes with newer JDK than is your server (probably in development environment you have 1.8 and in tomcat server you have 1.7).

Try switching Java compiler level to lower version in development environment.

Comment: Thank you for reply.I can delete errors.very thank you.